# How to open a 3dmax or maya file in flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d

Hi i want to open a 3d max file and do some rotation of a 3dmax object in flash action script 3.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some 3d Engines that makes this simpler

If you're doing just rotation, I suppose Sophie 3d might be the easiest http://www.sophie3d.com/

other that that the two go-to libraries are Away 3d and Papervision (in order of *my* preference)

http://www.away3d.com/

http://pv3d.org/

The way you would go about using these is to get Collada to convert your 3d Max object into an xml-readable scheme that away3d and pv3d support

http://www.collada.org/

after some quick googling of collada 3d tutorial found this, though there might be more out there  http://www.wazim.com/Collada_Tutorial_1.htm

hope this helps...

Comment: Okey Thank you, I think this will help me

Comment: @coderex you dont need to thanx, but accept the answer or voteup. thanks why you have 47% acceptance?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are two ways to get a 3D model (3DS, Maya, etc.) into a Flash application:

1. Render the 3D scene to video, and output the video in Flash (this will not be interactive).
2. Import your scene into [Swift 3D](http://www.erain.com/), which can then export to Flash.

Beyond that, 3D would have to be generated from within Flash, or you'd have to know the file format and read in the points, normals, textures, etc. from the model file (exporting to *.x or *.fbx might help, and their text formats are comparatively easy to interpret; make sure you don't use the binary versions of x/fbx).

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Sandy3D](http://www.flashsandy.org/) can directly import 3DS files (as well as COLLADA and ASE) into a scene.

If you've never worked with Sandy3D before, they've got several handy [tutorials](http://www.flashsandy.org/tutorials/3.0) posted to help you get started.